# dlib face landmark issue

Tags: c#, dlib

I'm using the DlibDotNet which is a c# wrapper to dlib. I capture a frame from the camera and calculate the landmarks. Seems to be pretty accurate. However after face detection, I inflate the rectangle so that the rectangle around the face is larger. I noticed the larger I inflate the rectangle i.e 60pixel the face landmarks seems to be random and moves around a lot. Is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is expected.  Don't do that.  The rectangle seeds the landmark localizer.  If you change the rectangle to some other shape it's going to mess it up.